# Basis for the eigenspace

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am the beginner. I need your help to find the basis for the eigenspace of the following matrix
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2\\
        -2 & -1\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
I have already found that

\begin{align}\lambda_1 &= i\sqrt3 \\
\lambda_2 &= -i\sqrt3 \end{align}

Comment: Then solve for $A \vec v = \lambda \vec v$ with those two eigenvalues.

Comment: “I am the beginner” — I didn't know there's only one. :-)

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: Is the base vector space $\mathbb C^2$? This matrix has no real eigenvectors.